# DISTINCT and GROUP BY with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, distinct

I have the following table (sql server) and i'm looking for a query to select the last two rows with all fields:

- order by **created_at**
- group by / distinct **type_id**

  ```
  id type_id some_value created_at 
  1  B       mk2        2016-10-01 00:00:00.000
  2  A       mbs        2016-10-01 10:02:39.077
  3  B       sa         2016-10-02 10:03:08.123
  4  A       xc         2016-10-02 10:03:28.777
  5  B       q1         2016-10-03 10:04:20.920
  6  A       tr         2016-10-03 10:04:48.533
  7  A       1a         2016-09-30 10:36:26.287
  ```

In MySQL its an easy task - but with **SQL Server** all fields have to be contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. But that results in field combinations that does not exist.

Is there a way to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Select top 2 * from table order by created_at desc`?

Comment: Why _all fields be contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause_ doesn't work for you?

Comment: you can use row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY type_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rown - you can do that maybe in a CTE or an inner sub query, then select rown=1

Comment: added solution - thanks @andrew-deighton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Based on the comment from Andrew Deighton i did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
         id,
         type_id,
         some_value,
         created_at,
         ROW_NUMBER()
         OVER (PARTITION BY type_id
           ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS row
       FROM test_sql
     ) AS ts
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY row
```

Conclusion: No need for **GROUP BY** and **DISTINCT**.